Movie or tv show episode where a character sends hands outline via fax
My mom is looking for a movie scene or a tv show episode where a following gag happens:
A character X (a man) has a friend/relative who makes leather gloves. X and some of his friends want to have gloves made for them so they outline their hands on sheets of paper and then X is supposed to send those outlines using a fax machine to the gloves maker to know each person's hand size. Unfortunately, X messes up the fax (enlarges the "message") so the outlines he sends are bigger than in reality which of course results in the gloves being too big.
The show/movie is American or British, probably a sitcom or a comedy. Set in 90s(?) based on the fact that fax machines were used.
We tried googling it but didn't get anything.
